# How to list hosts with larger than average RAM?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, json-query

Ansible has already done the "facts-gathering", and each host in `hostvars` already has the `ansible_memory_mb.real.total` set.

How do I select the host(s) with that number being above average for all of them? There is got to be a Jinja filtering one-liner, that I cannot figure out...

Answer (score 3):

For example, extract the variables you want to

```yaml
  mems: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|
            map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_memfree_mb')|
            list }}"
```

```yaml
  mems:
  - 99
  - 84
  - 86
```

---

Note: To extract `ansible_memory_mb.real.total` try

```yaml
  mems: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|
            map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_memmory_mb','real','total'])|
            list }}"
```

---

and create the dictionary

```yaml
  hosts_mems: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|zip(mems)) }}"
```

```yaml
  hosts_mems:
    host01: 99
    host02: 84
    host03: 86
```

Calculate the average

```yaml
  mems_average: "{{ hosts_mems.values()|sum / hosts_mems.values()|length }}"
```

```yaml
  mems_average: '89.66666666666667'
```

and select the hosts with more memory than average

```yaml
  hosts_mems_high: "{{ hosts_mems|dict2items|
                       selectattr('value', 'gt', mems_average|int)|items2dict }}"
```

```yaml
  hosts_mems_high:
    host01: 99
```

If you want a 'Jinja filtering one-liner', i.e. if you want to reduce the number of the variables make substitutions as you like.

---

Example of a complete playbook and inventory for testing

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
all:
  hosts:
    host01:
      ansible_memfree_mb: 99
      ansible_memmory_mb:
        real:
          total: 512
    host02:
      ansible_memfree_mb: 84
      ansible_memmory_mb:
        real:
          total: 1024
    host03:
      ansible_memfree_mb: 86
      ansible_memmory_mb:
        real:
          total: 2048
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    mems: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|
      map('extract', hostvars, 'ansible_memfree_mb')|list }}"
    mems_total: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|
      map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_memmory_mb','real','total'])|list }}"
    hosts_mems: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|zip(mems)) }}"
    mems_average: "{{ hosts_mems.values()|sum / hosts_mems.values()|length }}"
    mems_averag2: "{{ hosts_mems.values()|list|json_query('avg(@)') }}"
    mems_high: "{{ mems|select('gt', mems_average|int) }}"
    hosts_mems_high: "{{ hosts_mems|dict2items|
      selectattr('value', 'gt', mems_average|int)|items2dict }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |-
          mems:
            {{ mems|to_nice_yaml|indent(2) }}
          mems_total:
            {{ mems_total|to_nice_yaml|indent(2) }}
          hosts_mems:
            {{ hosts_mems|to_nice_yaml|indent(2) }}
          mems_average: {{ mems_average }}
          mems_averag2: {{ mems_averag2 }}
          mems_high: {{ mems_high }}
          hosts_mems_high:
            {{ hosts_mems_high|to_nice_yaml }}
      run_once: true
```

```yaml
  msg: |-
    mems:
      - 99
      - 84
      - 86
  
    mems_total:
      - 512
      - 1024
      - 2048
  
    hosts_mems:
      host01: 99
      host02: 84
      host03: 86
  
    mems_average: 89.66666666666667
    mems_averag2: 89.66666666666667
    mems_high: [99]
    hosts_mems_high:
      host01: 99
```

Comment: Thanks, @Vladimir. But this method works, but turns dictionary into list -- and then zip-ing back into dictionary -- multiple times.  Is there nothing shorter -- and faster? Say, with `hostvars | json_query(......)`?

Comment: If you find any tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is, how I ended up doing it. Not exactly a *one*-liner -- I need to calculate the average RAM first, which I do pretty much like @Vladimir-Botka suggests in his answer.

My method avoids the `dict2items` and the `zip`, however, which, in my opinion, makes it superior:

```yaml
- name: Figure out, if there is a business server with spare RAM
  set_fact:
    spareserver: >-
      {{ (groups.business |
        map('extract', hostvars) |
        selectattr('ansible_memory_mb.real.total', 'gt', avgram | float) |
        first).ansible_hostname }}
  vars:
    ramsizes: >-
      {{ groups.business |
        map('extract', hostvars, [
            'ansible_memory_mb', 'real', 'total'
        ]) |
        list }}
    avgram: '{{ (ramsizes | sum) / (ramsizes | length) }}'
```

Observations:

1. The need of the explicit conversion to `float` is either a bug or a very annoying "feature". The value of `avgram` was a result of an arithmetic expression -- why is the transient task variable recorded as a *string*, which must be forced back into float again? With a possible loss of precision too?
2. I apply `map('extract')` to `hostvars` twice -- I don't like this, but I don't know, how to avoid it -- suggestions welcome.
3. I still don't understand, why `json_query` was not working. The below was not producing any errors -- but the `spareserver` was *empty*.

```yaml
- set_fact:
    spareserver: >-
      {{ hostvars | json_query('[?ansible_memory_mb.real.total > `{{ avgram }}`]') }}
```

4. Whoever downgraded my question on account of my asking Vladimir for a better solution, should stop using StackOverflow.